# How does MinIO deals with sharding?

Tags: minio

I have been using [MinIO](https://min.io/) for a while now, but I have always used it for smaller than 1GB files.

I have a MinIO setup with 4 VMs each one with 2 disks (each disks of 100GB), and I would like to know if there is any problem if I try to copy files bigger than 400GB and also I would like to know how does the [Sharding](https://www.techtarget.com/searchoracle/definition/sharding) works on MinIO.

I do know how to use and configure Sharding in SDS as Gluster, but I find no reference on the internet so far about MinIO.